# Nested Sequence that plays fine alone shows up as entirely black in Master Sequence

Tags: video, premiere, video-editor, audio

I'm running Adobe Premiere Pro on a Mac, and after benching a project for a while and now coming back to it, some of the nested sequences will play just fine in their timeline, but show up as audio with video blacked out in the master sequence timeline.

Here is what the nested sequence looks like playing from its own timeline:

[image: Nested Sequence Plays Fine from Its Own Timeline]

Now here is what it looks like when used in the master sequence:

[image: Nested Sequence Shows Up as All Black in Master Sequence]

Notice how it appears as all black both in the source monitor and in the program monitor.

**What is this and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing all rendered caches? That would be my first guess.

Comment: This would actually make a lot of sense, as Premiere Pro separately renders the audio and video, and part of the nested sequence which wasn't used contained offline video before I removed it

Comment: I deleted the entire preview files directory, and re-rendering the project doesn't change the black.